# Compiler error when trying to instantiate my own class

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to create an instance of a class, `Dog`, but the compiler does not recognize the class and won't instantiate it. I tried copying the initializers from `Pet`, the superclass, into `Dog`, but that didn't make it work. Why can't I instantiate the `Dog` object?

Pet.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Pet : NSObject
{
    // Some ivars
}

//Randomizer
+(id)randomPet;

//Initializer 
-(id)initName:(NSString *)name
initColor:(NSString *)color
initBreed:(NSString *)breed;

// Getters and setters...

@end
```

Pet.m

```
#import "Pet.h"

@implementation Pet

+(id)randomPet
{
   // Empty 
}

-(id)initName:(NSString *)name
    initColor:(NSString *)color
    initBreed:(NSString *)breed;
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        // Initialization...
    }
    return self;

}

@end
```

Dog.h

```
#import "Pet.h"

@interface Dog : Pet
-(id)initName:(NSString *)name initColor:(NSString *)color
    initBreed:(NSString *)breed;

// Getters and setters...
@end
```

Dog.m

```
#import "Dog.h"

@implementation Dog

+(id)RandomPet
{
    // Snip...
}

- (id)initName:(NSString *)name
        initColor:(NSString *)color
        initBreed:(NSString *)breed;
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        // Initialization...
    }
    return self;
}
```

main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Pet.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool
    {
        Dog *d = [[Dog alloc] init]];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you compile this? Did you read the error message?

Comment: There's a lot of extraneous material here that makes this question really unlikely to help anyone else. Step one in solving a problem like this is to localize it -- reduce the code to the minimum that still exhibits the problem. See http://sscce.org/ for some helpful info about that. Since I happen to know what's extraneous, I'm going to heavily edit this so that there's a chance a future reader will be able to get some value out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have following errors:

1. Instead of `#import Pet.h` use `#import Dog.h`
2. `Dog *d = [[Dog alloc] init]];` should be `Dog *d=[Dog alloc]init];`
3. No need to re-define same method in sub class as they are in super class.

Apart from these answer, I would like to add few more things, these are not errors but it will add to your cocoa programming style and habbit :

The method

```
//Initializer 
-(id)initName:(NSString *)name
initColor:(NSString *)color
initBreed:(NSString *)breed;
```

does not go with standards, it should have been as :

```
//Initializer 
-(id)initName:(NSString *)name withColor:(NSString *)color withBreed:(NSString *)breed;
```

---

In the following lines

```
int petId;
while(petId != 1 && petId!=2)
```

What about initializing with `petID=0;`? If its garbage value become 1 then it will never enter the loop.

---

You can use @property to create property.

Comment: @JoshCaswell : I was giving answers but some problem occured. Now I have updated but even duskwuff has changed his anwer. :(

Answer (score 1):

You are not importing Dog into your method that has the main method. Add:

```
#import "Dog.h"
```

under the pet import. You might want to consider putting all your domain objects in one header.

Comment: Combining multiple interfaces into a single header file is not standard practice in Objective-C.

Comment: That's funny, one of the Apple engineers mentions that it can be done now since the compiler's smart enough to not get tripped up by seeing the same file in many places, in a WWDC session from 2012.

Comment: Oh, it can be done, sure. It's just not standard practice, is all. Doing it will confuse people. :)

Comment: Once you start using CoreData, you'll quickly get sick of importing each entity and the category.

Answer (score 1):

A few things I noticed:

- Your `main.m` will need to import `Dog.h`, not just `Pet.h`, as it refers specifically to the `Dog` class.
- Your interface in `Dog.h` redeclares a bunch of methods that are already declared in the parent class. You don't need to do this -- all classs implicitly support all methods defined on the parent class. It's your decision whether they need a unique implementation or not, but it doesn't need to be stated in the header.
- Neither `-[Dog init]` nor `-[Pet init]` is implemented. Perhaps you want the (incompletely implemented) `+[Dog randomPet]` method?

Comment: I don't see `Dog *[d [[Dog alloc] init]` anywhere in the question's revisions, and OP indicated below the deleted answer here that the missing `@end`s were just copy-paste errors, so I've removed those items from your answer to keep focus on the actual issue.

Comment: The `Dog *[d [[Dog alloc] init]` bit was in a part of `main.m` that you edited out.

Comment: I don't see the extra bracket, just the missing assignment operator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14554617/2 -- right near the bottom.

Comment: I see `Dog *d [[Dog alloc] init]];`, which does indeed have an extra bracket that I wasn't seeing, but on the right side, not between the `*` and `d` (and I missed it when editing the question, too). Neither I nor my ⌘F see `Dog *[d [[Dog alloc init]`. I do apologize if you're miffed at my editing, though. I'm just trying to salvage this question, because without some focus I think it deserves downvotes, close votes, and deletion -- it's not going to help anyone else.

Comment: I might have introduced the (extra) error in transcription. Either way it was an obvious syntax error that'd have needed fixing -- although I'd certainly hope that the IDE would make that plain enough.